# How to use a viewBinding in BottomNavigation

Tags: android, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to implement a bottomBarNavigation as I'm practicing how to use it. I'm confused , my menu is not showing as I'm trying to initialize it to a fragment. Please how do I do it?. Im still figuring how to use viewBinding.

these are my code :

**Menu**

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/nv_home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_contact_background"/> 


<item
    android:id="@+id/nv_notification"
    android:title="Notification"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_contact_background"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/nv_profile"
    android:title="Profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_contact_background"/>
```

**Activity**

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMain2Binding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    supportActionBar?.hide()

    val oneFragment = OneFragment()
    val twoFragment = TwoFragment()
    val threeFragment = ThreeFragment()

    setCurrentFragment(oneFragment)

    binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            binding.nv_home-> setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)  // this is what I intended doing but the nv_home is not showing.
        }
    }
}

private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment : Fragment) = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
    replace(binding.frame_fragment,fragment)
    commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the official documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding):

> View binding is a feature that allows you to more easily write code that interacts with views. Once view binding is enabled in a module, it generates a binding class for each XML layout file present in that module. An instance of a binding class contains direct references to all views that have an ID in the corresponding layout.

The view binding is available for the layout files as its using the `findviewbyId(R.id.viewid)` and in the case of menu items we use the `menu.findItem(R.id.menuid)` so the menu id's won't available in the binding variables

for the bottomnaviagtion use the menu id like this:

```
 binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.nv_home-> {
                 setCurrentFragment(firstFragment)
             }
              }
```